# Prove that in a vector space $V$ over field $\mathbb{F}$ $0\cdot v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that in a vector space $V$ over field $\mathbb{F}\space$:
$0\cdot v=0$ for all $v \in V$

I started by proving that for all $x \in F$
$x \cdot 0 = 0$ using the Field axioms.

Then I said that multiplying a vector $v = (a_1,a_2,...)$ by a scalar $\alpha$ is like multiplying each of the elements of the vector by $\alpha$ so that $\alpha \cdot v = (\alpha \cdot a_1, \alpha \cdot a_2,...)$

So for $\alpha = 0$, $v$ would be the $0$ vector, and thus $v = 0$.

Comment: Your proof tries to use a very particular, limited form of a vector as an $\,n$-coordinates one. There are linear spaces where vectors cannot be expressed that way.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Could you expand or explain yourself better? Can my proof be fixed to include those linear spaces where vectors cannot be expressed as an n-coordinates?

Comment: Of course I could...but not here. Anyway, if you take the vector space of all real functions, or all differentiable functions, or all continuous functions, or...then you can't express vectors (functions) as you did above..and these are just a few examples. The best proof for your quest is the one given by Federica, though I'd rather say "Now add the additive inverse of $\,0\cdot\vec v\,$ to both sides", instead of calling that "cancellation law"...just to be a little more formal wrt the axioms, but of course both things, here, are one and the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$0\cdot\vec v=(0+0)\cdot \vec v=0\cdot \vec v+0\cdot\vec v$$
Now use cancellation law in the additive group of vector space.

Comment: I understand there are several ways to prove it but I was wondering if my proof is good, and if not what's not good at it.

Comment: @Georgey i think your proof is correct, the only thing a bit strange is that it seems to assume that V is finite dimensional. Moreover, it is usual to avoid the choice of a basis, if the proof can be made in totally general settings

Comment: Where did I write in the proof that $V$ is finite? $v = (a_1,a_2,...a_n)$ ?

Comment: @Georgey Yes, that's the point

Comment: $\forall \space n \in \mathbb{N}$ will correct it?

Comment: @Georgey to say $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ is equivalent to say "for every FINITE-dimensional vector space of dimension $n$", so i would simply say:...."a vector $\vec v=(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$..." without specifying the number of components

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni That still implies that there's a basis which is at most countably infinite. Which is the same thing is requiring finite dimension, since the cardinality of a basis is always either finite or uncountable.

Comment: @fgp very interesting, thank you for correction

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni Ups, I just realized I made a mistake there. There are, in fact, vector spaces with countably infinite bases. What I said remains true for most commonly used vector spaces with inifinite dimension, though. E.g. complete banach spaces (i.e., complete normed spaces) cannot have a countable base. One can extend that to at least complete metrizable spaces, I think...